# Filter Union Type to Single Type

Tags: flowtype

I have a tagged union type defined, and there are places in my code where I want to filter that down to a single type.

```
/* @flow */

type AbstractChange = {
    base: string,
};

type CreateChange = AbstractChange & { 
    kind: 'create',
    createField: string,
};

type UpdateChange = AbstractChange & { 
    kind: 'update',
    updateField: string,
};

type Change = CreateChange | UpdateChange;

function test(changes: Change[]) {
  let creates: CreateChange[] = changes.filter(c => c.kind === 'create');

  return creates;
}
```

Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be allowed, I get the error:

```
19: function test(changes: Change[]) {
                           ^ intersection. This type is incompatible with 7:

type CreateChange = AbstractChange & {                        
                                     ^ object type
```

[Here's](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCARgM4YBOAhgMYYDCAFlQHYDmBAvGAN6pgCwxKqTwAuMOQoBLdgBpUAXwDc6bPjD0KeKhjxNWHMNxJTaDZuwIAyXmH5gAkAGtZAEwkByGtt15PCgKOPjp6AGLSeDAekpSybAoqargEAKo4bn4GVsZEZJTm2Ua2PPZBriwxngCuGX4BDo61meGR0RJS8YmqmCmalkbcWqH6AwQAPmDpLaOGeD1Q1Sx00nAsYHrkABQ0Y6QSRXgA2gC6AJS8DjB4GGAhfvuavnqHp7m7c6QAdFDSMHoUHbGAB8dy+FTcxk43G8z38Z1UAgc2gw1Qo63um1UiiAA) a try flow link if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` is not smart enough to understand such a refinement, however it understands maybe types

```
function maybeCreateChange(c: Change): ?CreateChange {
  return c.kind === 'create' ? c : null
}

function test(changes: Change[]): CreateChange[] {
  return changes.map(maybeCreateChange).filter(Boolean)
}
```